# How can we give link to another activity when i press some numbers(example 645378) in dial pad?

Tags: android-layout, android-intent, android-widget, android

How can we give link to another activity when i press some numbers(example 645378) in dial pad? and after entering this number in dial pad and when call button is pressed then i want to go for another activity. Is it possible? can anyone suggest with an example?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, through a Broadcast Receiver, it does seem possible.

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/01/processing-ordered-broadcasts.html

Can you build what you want from the example given?